# PL/SQL Block in oracle11g

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have to the following question but what I have tried keeps giving me an error.
Create a PL/SQL query to display the product name, product price and delivery description. Only display the records where the difference between the despatch date and delivery date is greater than three days. In your query also determine whether the product is a premium or non-premium product.

This is what I have attempted.

```
set SERVEROUTPUT on;
DECLARE
p_product VARCHAR2(50);
p_price VARCHAR2(50);
d_description VARCHAR2(50);
d_days NUMBER(3.0);
p_productcat VARCHAR2(50);
cursor INFO IS
select p.Product, p.Price, d."Description", d.despatchdate || d.deliverydate as "Delivery Days"
from product p, delivery d
where d.deliverydate ('dd')- d.despatchdate('dd') > 3;
begin
open INFO;
loop
if (p_price > 15000) then
p_productcat:='Premium Product';
else
p_productcat:='Non Premium Product';
end if;
exit when INFO%NOTFOUND;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PRODUCT:'|| p_product||chr(30)||'PRICE:'||p_price||chr(13)||'DESCRIPTION:'|| 
d_description || chr(50) || 'DELIVERY DAYS:' || d_days || chr(13) || 'PRODUCT CATEGORY:' || 
p_productcat);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('----------------------------------------------');
end loop;
close info;
end;
```

The error is:

Error starting at line : 254 in command
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 10, column 30:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "D"."DESPATCHDATE": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 8, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Answer (score 1):

Ah! Mystery! I love that! But - not that much in coding. Saying that there are errors - *which* errors?

Until you respond, here's what looks suspicious:

- `d."Description"` - unless column is created using double quotes, this won't work. Use `d.description` instead
- don't compare days in a month (unless you're sure that those dates will always be in the same month). Use `WHERE d.deliverydate - d.despatchdate > 3`. Or, if you *insist*, apply the `TO_CHAR` function: `WHERE to_char(d.deliverydate, 'dd') - to_char(d.despatchdate, 'dd') > 3`

Comment: It says that column named DESPATCHDATE doesn't exist in table DELIVERY.

Comment: Error report -
ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 1000000 bytes
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 32
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 97
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 112
ORA-06512: at line 20
20000. 00000 -  "%s"
*Cause:    The stored procedure 'raise_application_error'
           was called which causes this error to be generated.
*Action:   Correct the problem as described in the error message or contact
           the application administrator or DBA for more information.

Comment: You're displaying too much data for current buffer size. Run `set serveroutput on size unlimited`

Comment: DO NOT set your server output unlimited. That is exactly what you will get, at least until you fill all available memory.  You have created and opened an Explicit cursor. But there is no fetch in your loop and failure to fetch does not set cursor%notfound attribute. Your loop will never exit.  Either FETCH the cursor within the loop or convert to an IMPLICIT cursor.

Comment: Ha! Good catch, @Belayer - no FETCH!

Comment: Evidently you need `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` within a development or testing environment. It prints out the produced result on the command line, most probably you won't need within the production environment, rather you'll use a reporting tool. So just restrict your data coming from the query by some criteria within the WHERE clause in order to get rid of buffer overflow issue @Sileshan